# Which of these storage methods is fastest?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

1 million users, each only needing their OWN data set of 100 strings (approx 255 characters each).  Each accesses once each day, doing 2 reads (all data) and 1 write per day (1 string)

- mysql
- amazon EC2 + simpleDB
- amazon EC2 + flat file system (text files + php)
- amazon EC2 + sqllite - removed as it can't handle it.

Which is fastest?

Comment: For the level of data you're reading/writing (v.small) I don't think it's going to matter...

Comment: ? 3 million read/writes of approx 1000 bytes a day is small?

Comment: Amazon was getting 130 million page views a day in Jan 2010. How many bytes per page?

Comment: It's 35 queries per second on average. It's small.

Comment: @MPelletier: size is everything! ;)

Comment: @MitchWheat The other school of thought being of course that size does not matter so much as how it is used.

Comment: @@MPelletier: I was talking about databases! :)

Comment: @MitchWheat So was I! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local mySQL is almost certainly going to be faster than a remote/cloud data storage, but depends on network speeds, server configuration, etc.

Comment: The site and data storage would be both on Amazon in 2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single SQLite database file for all those users, expect it to die. Despite the hype and theoretical specs of being able to handle Terabyte-sized databases, SQLite does not handle millions of records all that well. Of course, the limit is not precise, depends highly on table design.